# Div spaces look different on Firefox and Chrome (and localhost even different)

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why my page div has different spaces on Firefox and Chrome (and Edge). Also, when I open it on localhost, it is even more moved, so I have to move my div more than what I see on localhost.

that part is in a div called "press2" and it looks like this

```
.press2  {
        margin-left:220px;
        position:absolute;
        top:1000px;
        width:580px;
}
```

The "top" part is what I have had to edit. When I look at the page on localhost (Wampserver) it is still about 100px further away, and overlaps with the review div above it

```
.review  {
        margin-left:270px;
        position:absolute;
        top:550px;
        width:400px;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Redo your page so that everything is positioned normally instead of using position absolute everywhere

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? If the browser uses browser predefined css, then it is quite normal that you have spaces. I would remove absolute positioning and everything will look fine.

Comment: Add some screenshot instead of the link to your website, don't use `position:absolute` everywhere.

Comment: screenshots added

Comment: From your screenshots it looks like the line height is larger in Firefox than in Chrome for whatever reason. It isn't on my machine though; the live site looks fine in both browsers here.

Comment: Have you tried the answer below? Short answer, set line-height on body

Comment: @Huangism But your first comment is a far better answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is better with the line space set. Still weird on localhost though, vbut that doesn't matter much. I will have to update the whole thing later with no absolute position, it is a remnant from when I made it many years ago, never changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use line-height in body

```
body{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 12pt;
}
```